# Create a another associative array inside existing array

Tags: php, arrays, associative-array

I am trying to create an array inside an array so that I can encode it into JSON.  I want my array to be like the following:

```
<pre>Array
(
    [user] => John Smith
              Array
        (
            [profile] => 
            [podcast] => Array
                (
                    [0] => stdClass Object
                        (
                            [id] => 4
                            [title] => How to display array inside array?
                            [description] => Unexpected array being displayed!
                            [category] => 1
                            [duration] => 0:05:05
                            [audio] => http://demo.web/uploads/podAudio/PodAudio-20190114102432822.mp3
                            [image] => http://demo.web/uploads/podImage/PodImage-20190114102432145.jpg
                            [added_by] => 1
                            [updated_date] => 
                        )

                )

        )

)
</pre>
```

Following is my code for getting arrays:

```
<?php  
    $userList = $user->getAllUserName();

    foreach ($userList as $users) { 
        $fullname = $users->full_name;
        $profile = $users->image;
        $id = $users->id;

        $podcastList = $podcast->getUserPodcast($id);

        if (!empty($podcastList)) {
            $output = array(
            'name'  => $fullname,
            'profile'   => $profile,
            'podcast' => $podcastList
        );
        }

    }


    $json = array(
        'user'  => $output
    );
    echo "<pre>";
    print_r($json);
    echo "</pre>";
?>
```

However, the above code is giving me an array which looks like this:

```
    <pre>Array
           (
    [user] => Array
        (
            [name] => Lenna Smith
            [profile] => 
            [podcast] => Array
                (
                    [0] => stdClass Object
                        (
                            [id] => 4
                            [title] => How to display array inside array?
                            [description] => Unexpected array being displayed!
                            [category] => 1
                            [duration] => 0:05:05
                            [audio] => http://demo.web/uploads/podAudio/PodAudio-20190114102432822.mp3
                            [image] => http://demo.web/uploads/podImage/PodImage-20190114102432145.jpg
                            [added_by] => 1
                            [updated_date] => 
                        )

                )

        )

)
</pre>
```

Is there any code to be replaced or added so that I can the get desired array? Any suggestion will be appreciated.

Comment: Your desire output doesn't make sense - you cannot have `[user] => John Smith` as array. Maybe you want to have "John Smith" as key?

Comment: Is this PHP? Please always include language (and possible framework) as tags.

Comment: Do I have to change code to get the desired output? If so what do I need to add and where?

Comment: You cannot change to code to get that output as your desire output has syntax error

Comment: @David Winder, is that possible to set "John Smith" as key and inside it have associative arrays with key and value?

Comment: Yes, as key its possible - you can have array of user when the key to each element will be the user name. will that be fine for you?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Simply making the following changes helped me.

```
<?php 
    $userList = $user->getAllUserName();

    foreach ($userList as $users) { 
        $fullname = $users->full_name;
        $profile = $users->image;
        $id = $users->id;

        $podcastList = $podcast->getUserPodcast($id);

        if (!empty($podcastList)) {
            $output[$fullname] = array(
            'profile'   => $profile,
            'podcast' => $podcastList
        );
        }

    }    

    $json = array(
        'user'  => $output
    );   
     echo "<pre>";
    print_r($json);
    echo "</pre>";
    ?>
```